# Compact Sets of $(X,d)$ with discrete metric

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $X \neq \emptyset$. Define the discrete metric on $X$ with:
>   $
>     d(x,y)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll} 1, & x \neq y \\
>          0, & x=y\end{array}\right.$
>
> (a) Ascertain the compact sets in $(X,d)$.
>
> (b) Ascertain the continuous functions $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$.

I'm really confused about this tasks because I don't know what I have to do exactly. My ideas:

(a) First all sets in (X,d) are open and closed, because in a ball $B(x,r)$ there is only the element $x$ and all singletons are open. So $\bigcap F_{open}, F \subset X$ is open too. The complement of these $F$ are closed. So all sets are open closed. How I ascertain the compact sets in $(X,d)$? This means one can find unlasting open covers for $X$, but how far I can find the compact sets with these information?

(b) Unfortunately I haven't any idea..

Thanks for helping!

Comment: what is your definition of compact set? Every open covering has a finite subcovering? I hope so, because that makes things more easy.

Comment: $A$ is compact in $X$ iff $A$ is finite, and any function is continuous... ***WHY??***

Comment: @drhab Yes, it is. Sorry, i forgot to mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint on (a):

Note that any set $Y\subseteq X$ has the covering $\{\{y\}\mid y\in Y\}$ which is an **open cover** here (all sets are open, as you remark) and **has no subcover**. What are the consequences for infinite sets?

Hint on (b):

A function $f:X\to\mathbb R$ is not continuous if some open set $U\subseteq\mathbb R$ exists such that $f^{-1}(U)\subseteq X$ is not open. Now remember that all subsets of $X$ are open.

Comment: (b) Since all sets are open, every $f$ is continuous. Right?
(a) The open cover of $Y$ is $Y$ itself, do I have this right? If so, the infinite sets have finite subcovers. I'm not conviced about my answer, but this is the only conclusion I can find.

Comment: (b) Yes you are right. (a) Coverings of a set $Y$ are families $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ of subsets of $X$ with $Y\subset\bigcup_{i\in I}U_i$. So the family that only contains $Y$ itself is a covering of $Y$, but next to that also the collection of singletons: $({y}_{y\in Y}$ is a covering of $Y$. It seems that you are speaking of the first, but in my answer I mean the second. If $Y$ is infinite then this covering has infinite members. Since the sets of the covering are open and it has no finite subcover we must conclude that infinite sets are not compact. Finite sets are compact here.

Comment: In my former comment I introduced coverings of $Y$ as families of subsets of $X$. Another way (used in my answer) is to look at them as subsets of the powerset of $X$. Then the family $(U_i)_{i\in I}$ corresponds with the set $\{U_i\mid i\in I\}$. Special cases (also mentioned in my former comment) are then the coverings $\{Y\}$ and $\{\{y\}\mid y\in Y\}$. The second one is mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Let $C$ be a compact set. As every set is open, for each $c \in C$ the set $\{c\}$ is open and $\bigcup_{c\in C}\{c\}$ is an open cover of $C$. 
Now, it must have a finite subcover, which tells you that $C$ is finite. The converse is not hard to show.

For b. use the characterizations of continuous functions via the inverse image of open sets, that is $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for open $U$. When all sets are open in $X$ this is however no restrictions whatsoever, whence all functions are continuous.